# Synchronizing stacks between threads

Tags: c, pthreads

Im working on a client (that use a GUI and a socket). The GUI (running on the main thread) create on the fly commands of my protocol, every time I create a new command I append it in a dynamic stack.

In another thread (using pthread), I check if there is a command in the stack then send it progressively using a socket (which is non-block btw). When the command on the top of the stack is done sending I pop the stack (which means that the command is removed and each commands below the first element are pushed up).

Now as you might guess I have huge problems to synchronize that... I try to use some flags, mutex but I always end up with some access violation on the memory.

Basically what Im doing is this:

In the main thread when (ie) the user press a button:

```
char cmd[ 50 ] = "My new protocol command";

AppendCommandToSendStack( cmd );
```

In another thread:

```
if( SendStackCount )
{
     SendCommand( 0 ); // 0 = The top of the stack.

     if( IsCommandDoneSending( 0 ) )
     {
          RemoveCommandFromStack( 0 );
     }
}
```

Can anybody help me or give me some pointers on how to make this mechanism work. Or another approach that would result in the same or similar workflow as Im trying to implement.

Tks in advance!

[ Update ]

I start reading on semaphore and it seems thats exactly what I need... however it doesn't seems to work... this is what Im doing in pseudo code:

```
sem_t mutex;

int stack_count;

command *stack;

main()
{
    // Init & Connect client.

    // Start Thread

    sem_init( &lock_stack, 0, 1 );

    while( 1 )
    {
        sem_wait( &lock_stack );

        ++stack_count;

        stack = ( command * ) realloc( stack, stack_count * sizeof( command ) );

        strcpy( stack[ stack_count - 1 ].cmd, "new command" );

        sem_post( &lock_stack );
    }
}


thread()
{
    while( 1 )
    {
        sem_wait( &lock_stack );

        if( stack_count )
        {
            // Send stack[ 0 ].cmd via socket then when done pop the stack like this:

            --stack_count;

            if( 0 < stack_count )
            {
                memcpy( &stack[ 0 ],
                    &stack[ 1 ],
                    ( stack_count - 1 ) * sizeof( command ) );
            }        
        }

        sem_post( &lock_stack );
    }
}
```

Since Im basically new to this am I missing something obvious, because I still have memory access violation that "seems" to happen randomly on the stack array.

Comment: Please improve your accept rating by accepting some answers to your questions. Also "*I try to use some flags, mutex but I always end up with some access violation on the memory.*" is very vague. Maybe you can provide some code for that?

Comment: As well as the semaphore that counts the stack entries and allows the producer to wait when there are no entries, you need to protect the stack against multiple access with a mutex or CriticalSection.  Also, why are you initializing the semaphore count to 1 when there are initially zero items on the stack?  Oh - and try to get rid of that realloc/memcpy stuff by only stacking pointers to dynamically-allocated objects/structs.  The realloc/memcpy to/from the stack has to take place while the queue is locked by the mutex - bad for contention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a classic example of producer-consumer problem. You want to `produce` commands, while other threads `consume` them. You can have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem which explains how to implement a basic producer-consumer problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be :

```
 Thread 1 :
       lock mutex
       put items on stack
       unlock mutex


  Thread 2 :
     loop
        lock mutex
        check item on stack
        if somthing get item on stack
        unlock mutex
```

A more effective soultion will be:

```
 Thread 1 :
      lock mutex
      put items on stack
      signal on conditionVariable
      unlock mutex

 Thread 2 : 
      lock mutex 
      check item on stack 
      if none wait on conditionVariable
      // here you will be woke up when there is a signal
      get item on the stack
      unlock mutex
      do your work
```

Comment: your more effective solution contains a deadlock, when thread 2 waits on the condition variable, thread 1 cant signal it, because it cant get the mutex. you need to temporarily release the mutex in thread 2 while waiting on the condition variable.

Comment: yep, true there should be two mutexes. one for the condition variable, one for synch between consumers.

Comment: @smerlin: assuming that the pthread condition variable APIs are used, the wait API is designed to be called while holding the mutex (it unlocks it at the appropriate time before blocking the thread).  In fact, it's an error to call `pthread_cond_wait()` while *not* holding the mutex.